# Cesium : Low frame rate when updating polyline position frequently

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I'm currently plotting the trajectory of a moving point with a PolylineCollection().
The application generates about 13,000 points that need to be added to the path one by one.
The issue I'm facing is that when the point moves I am required to update the entire array of positions in the polyline. as :

**polyline.positions = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArrayHeights(updatedBuffer);**

This operation has to be done for every point added to the path.

I was using PathGraphics to visualize the path by providing the position as a TimeIntervalCollection however my application provides the new Points in the path at runtime and position data is not known beforehand as such PathGraphics is not a viable option.
Also the frame rate using path graphics was as slow as updating polyline position.

I ran my application through the Chrome Profiler to see why the framerate was so low.

Based on the profiler the most time consuming operations are
updating the polyline positions in the above call and
Scene.render()
In Scene.render() the maximum time is taken in the call createVertexArrays()
From this I perceive that Cesium creates a new VertexArray for the polyline every time there is an update to position.

To improve performance I am considering disabling creation of a new  Vertex Array every time  and instead creating one large array.
Subsequent calls to update position would cause the position to be added via a call to glBufferSubData().

Is this a viable solution and if so can someone point out how I should go about doing this?

## Attachment : Profile screenshot       [image]

Comment: Looks like this was cross-posted and answered on [the Cesium forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cesium-dev/ZSCnAQF5RIM/StigNPBMCQAJ).

Comment: yeah...its been answered on the cesium forum